# Conditional splunk search based on regex

Tags: regex, logging, splunk, splunk-query

So I have these type of logs:

```
[2023-03-24 12:38:38,774] [INFO] - Tool - Finished scan cycle #20 for top URL = https://www.website.com/tool/ . Channel = mobile . Duration = 2h 52m 50s (seconds = 10370) . Total visited URLs = 3527. Max depth reached = 6.

[2023-03-24 09:45:38,482] [INFO] - Tool - Finished scan cycle #19 for top URL = https://www.website.com/tool/ . Channel = mobile . Duration = 2h 36m 10s (seconds = 9370) . Total visited URLs = 3326. Max depth reached = 6.
```

And my search looks like this:

```
index="xxxxx"  sourcetype="xxxxx"  host="xxxxx" AND "Finished scan cycle" AND "/tool" 
| timechart  min(seconds)
```

And I want to update the search to display only the logs which contains `Total visited URLs` < `a value i will set eg. 3000`.

For now I have the regex `URLs\s=\s(?<value>\d+).` but I don't know how to use this in splunk to search by this value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To filter on the visited URL count, put your regex in a `rex` command to extract the count from the event.  Then use the `where` command to keep only the desired values.

```
index="xxxxx"  sourcetype="xxxxx"  host="xxxxx" AND "Finished scan cycle" AND "/tool" 
| rex "URLs\s=\s(?<value>\d+)"
| where value < 3000
| timechart  min(seconds)
```